# How to pass a javascript variable to the parameter value of site_url?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make an ajax call :

```
function loadView(url_, target, pk, json_extra_data) {

  var ret = "";

  if (isNaN(pk) == false && typeof(pk) !== "boolean" && $.trim(pk) != "" && pk > 0) {

    if (target == "MN") {

      ret = $.ajax({
        data: json_extra_data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('meeting/modif'); ?>/" + pk,
        async: false
      }).responseText;

    } else if (target == "EQ") {

      ret = $.ajax({
        data: json_extra_data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('enquete/questionnaire'); ?>/" + pk,
        async: false
      }).responseText;

    }

  }

  return ret;

}
```

So how to put the javascript variable `url_` as the parameter value of `site_url` ?

Comment: Are you trying to call a PHP function from JavaScript?

Comment: yes , in fact it is a Codeigniter function ( PHP )

Comment: That’s not possible. PHP runs on the server, only then will the JS be available for the client. Port your `site_url` function to JS or make another AJAX call to generate the needed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call PHP inside a JS files. I suggest you create a global JS variable on your head tag that will contain the necessary info that you'll need and be called inside a JS file.

Your code should more or less look like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var site_url_questionaire = <?php echo site_url('enquete/questionnaire'); ?>;
        </script>
        <script src="some_js_file.js" type="text/javascript">
    </head>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can set Apache server to let PHP parse any (extension) file. But I would rather stick with proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's an added option for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you have external JS file you must declare global var like this
 for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/customjs/custom.js')?>"></script>
<script>
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
    var current_url = "<?php echo current_url();?>";
   </script>
```